# drop down menu on hover not working

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-hover

I have a dropdown menu so when a user hover overs to that button he should get  lists of option without clicking it. This is my dropdown menu:

```
<div class="Menu"">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="someAction" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Select Action
  <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a class="remove">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my hoverover code but for some reason its not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someAction').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    });
}); });
```

forgot to mention on click i should be able to select that option

Comment: What do you mean by `on click i should be able to select that option`?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/P9fpd/#&togetherjs=sl66BAsrcB] something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your selectors `.dropdown-menu`:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#someAction').hover(function () {
                  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
            }, function () {
                  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
            });
         });
```

You missed class selector dots in `.find()` function;

### UPDATE: Second part

Well, This may be your problem now: When you leave the button, dropdown fades out, so you cannot select any option.

That's because your hover selector is `#someAction`. Change it to `.dropdown-menu` and `#someAction` parent:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn-group').hover(function () {
                  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
            }, function () {
                  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
            });
         });
```

as well as this works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.Menu').hover(function () {
            ....
```

Don't forget to fadeOut `.dorpdown-menu` on an option click.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
})
```

Comment: but i cant select the option? so when i hover over it should display all my options and when i click on one of the option it should select that option

Comment: @Dip: Do you want to select dropdown options in `hover` function?

Comment: yes- how do i do that? because no point having something that have no actions

Comment: If you are trying to access options in hover function, this can be an example `$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').children('option')`.
I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, so provide us a jsFiddle and show what you are trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: But I guess you have some trouble with elements visibility, right?

Comment: this is the kind of thing i am try to do: jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/jrV6u/27 so when hover over the button a menu should appear and from that menu i should be able to select one the option. currently i cant select any option because menu disappears

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what's your problem pal! I think you need to complete your js. In your posted fiddle, nothing disappears!

Comment: ok, you see the method you've suggested works perfectly fine. but using that method i cannot select any element from my dropdown list. that link might have confused you have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/P9fpd/  - so what i want is when i hover over this drop down box i should get a list of options (without clicking a button) and from that option i should be able to select a option

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. there is no `.dropdown-menu` in button.Use:

```
 $('#someAction').hover(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  },function(){
     $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500)
 ;})
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3VQs/)**

Answer (score 0):

Get the dropdown with Class selector ('.dropdown-menu')

Answer (score 0):

**You have 2 little mistakes and 1 error:**

1st mistake on the HTML double quotes:

```
<div class="Menu"">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="Menu">
```

2nd mistake on the javascript close tag, and the **error** with the selector that you forget to type the `.` that is a css class selector:

You did:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#someAction').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
}); 
});//why another close tag? error.
```

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#someAction').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/M5jZ3/)**

You've done multiple mistakes.

1. You have an unnecessary `});` . Remove it.
2. You have an unncecessary doublequotes Menu div. Convert it to `<div class="Menu">`
3. Your button doesn't include dropdown-menu. Select dropdown-menu individually.

Now your code became:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Menu">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" id="someAction" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Select Action 
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="add">Add</a></li>
            <li><a class="remove">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut(); //Just hiding dropdown at first for testing purposes.
    $('#someAction').hover(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    }, function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You still cant choose any option before menu fades out.

In order to keep menu visible I changed your html

moved id="someAction" to the parent div

```
<div class="Menu">
    <div class="btn-group" id="someAction" style="float:left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Select Action 
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
        <li><a class="add">Add</a></li>
        <li><a class="remove">Remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3VQs/4/